# iOS: Autoreleased objects across NSTheads

Tags: ios, nsthread, autorelease

I gather that if I create an autoreleased object and I pass it to another thread to be worked on, this is bad if the first NSThread should happened to clean out its autorelease pool, or be killed. However if I want to avoid autoreleasing as a rule, what are some examples of where I cannot autorelease objects, particularly objects that I might want to share between NSThreads? It seems to me that most autoreleasing can be avoided.

Comment: You would probably have better luck using ARC and GCD

Comment: ARC? It's a good technology but using it feels like wearing a bib. As for GCD I don't want to use too much Apple-specific stuff as my code must also run on Android (native C++).

Comment: Well, I disagree about ARC since it's letting the compiler do what the compiler does best. Totally understand about the x-plat stuff though.

Comment: I can't see any reason you "cannot autorelease objects"

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the memory management rules. Threads make no difference. **A function only has to worry about what it does locally; it never has to worry about what any other function does.** A function needs to retain an object if it needs to be assigned to an instance variable or something like that. When something is retained, it needs to be balanced with a release.